# Fast algorithm that checks if a rectangle intersects any rectangle in space

Tags: geometry, 2d

What is the fastest algorithm or data structure to check if a rectangle intersects any other rectangle. I want to check if a space is occupied before placing an object.
All objects are rectangular and are axis aligned. If the space is available, I add the rectangle to this data structure for future intersection checks.

It seems like a Quad Tree is great for this but is there something faster that I don't know of?
I also don't clearly know the time complexity of a Quad Tree, some sources say its O(log n) others say O(n log n).

In short, I want to know if there exist a algorithm or data structure that can help me make fast checks of whether a rectangle fits in an area or if it already occupied by another rectangle.

Comment: Don't overthink it, and next time just do a bit of research... https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-two-rectangles-overlap/

Comment: [time complexity of classic search algorithms](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/notes/sorting-and-searching-algorithms-time-complexities-cheat-sheet/) might be considered if speed is a concern.

Comment: @PKramer That is not what I asked at all. I don't want to check 2 rectangles only, I want to know if a rectangle can fit in a space or if another rectangle occupies that space.

Comment: @ryyker I don't need the chart, I know time complexity. I don't know what time complexity Quad Tree has.

Comment: No offense intended but it just means your question was not clear enough for me. Do you mean rectangles in 2D or 3D with any kind of rotation? Do you mean rectangles in 3D on a 2D plane snapped to 90 degrees of rotation?

Comment: @PKramer Nonrotated Rectangles in 2D.

Comment: Oh do you mean rectangles in bitmaps?